# Tabbed dates for api content

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

in React i am attempting to add my api content to a series of tabs, so you click on a tab, and it will show any listings in the api matching that date.

my attempt, code of component is below

```
import context from "./apiContext";

import styled from "styled-components";
const Tab = styled.button`
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  ${({ active }) =>
    active &&
    `
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    opacity: 1;
  `}
`;
const ButtonGroup = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const tabs = ["18-08-20", "19-08-20", "20-08-20"];

function Movies() {
  const { films } = useContext(context);

  console.log(films);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(tabs[0]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="movies">
        <div className="title">
          <h1>
            Movies: <span />
            All Releases
          </h1>
          <div className="tab-menu">
            <ButtonGroup>
              {tabs.map((tab) => (
                <Tab
                  key={tab.label}
                  active={active === tab}
                  onClick={() => setActive(tab)}
                >
                  {tab.label}
                </Tab>
              ))}
            </ButtonGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          {films
            .filter((item) => item.PreShowStartTime === Date.parse({ active }))
            .map((item, index) => (
              <div class="card" key={index}>
                <div class="title">
                  <span class="title">{item.Title}</span>{" "}
                  <span>
                    {new Date(item.PreShowStartTime).toLocaleDateString("en", {
                      day: "2-digit",
                      month: "short"
                    })}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Movies;
```

To view with live API:

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-hoover-8hik2

On line 24, is my test array of dates, which also should show as the label of the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to format the dates returned by the API according to what you have defined in the `tabs` constant in your code (or vice versa). Currently your API returns example `2020-08-18T14:00:00` but your `tabs` has format `18-08-20`.

So for that, on your `filter` condition, you can use something like:

```
new Date(item.PreShowStartTime).toJSON().slice(2, 10) === active
```

where `active` is the active date selected on the tab

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-yonath-pv8i0?file=/src/Movies.js:1293-1357

As a side note, you were also accessing `tab.label` to print your tab labels. `tabs` does not contain a property named `label`...